# Querying the state of a class's listener

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have instantiated a class (class1) that loads some data via PHP in an AS3 Flex project.
I instantiate class1, which is asynchronous and utilizes a URLLoader() to obtain its data.

Then I would like to instantiate class2, which needs to USE the data from class1, but when I simply instantiate it I find that class1's instance variable is not populated yet because I am calling class2 too quickly.

How can I create such a dependency that will link correctly?
I am really new to using listeners, but I am imagining a listener in class2 might be what I need?
Or maybe I can pass a reference to the listener in class1 into class2?
I also know nothing about dispatching events... is this the key?

Here's an example in pseudo code:

```
var class1:myC1 = new myC1("http://some/url/to/utilize");
//this never shows up because it hasn't loaded at the time i request it
trace("the stuff from class1 is: ", class1.myXMLList);
//and of course i can't use it here either
var class2:myC2 = new myC2(0x000000, class1.myXMLList);
```

Thanks for any help,
jml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I'm posting this "pseudo code" hopping it will help

```
package {

  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
  import flash.net.*;

  public class Class1 extends EventDispatcher {
    private var _loader:URLLoader;

    public var data:XMLList;

    public function Class1(url:String) {
      _loader = new URLLoader();
      _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
      // rest of the code here ....

      _loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
      data = new XMLList(_loader.data); // probably wrong but
                                        // I figured you had already
                                        // implemented this part

      dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
  }
}
```

I figured class 2 might look like this

```
package {

  public class Class2 {

    // your stuff here

    public function Class2(color:uint, data:XMLList) {

    }
  }

}
```

The main class

```
package {

  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class Main extends Sprite {

    public var c1:Class1;
    public var c2:Class2;

    public function Main() {
      c1 = new Class1("http://some/url/to/utilize");
      c1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    }

    protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
      c2 = new Class2(0xffcc00, c1.data);
    }
  }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: cool.  thanks for the tips. i'll check it out and post back if i have any problems. 
much appreciated!

btw- do you have any links regarding learning about event dispatching?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Flex/FlashBuilder to autocomplete the events for your classes, you can use the "Event" metadata tag before your class definition. Based on the example above, it would look like this

```
package {

  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
  import flash.net.*;

  // use the "Event" metadata tag 

  [Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]

  public class Class1 extends EventDispatcher {

        private var _loader:URLLoader;

        public var data:XMLList;

        public function Class1(url:String) {
          _loader = new URLLoader();
          _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
          // rest of the code here ....

          _loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
        }

        protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
          data = new XMLList(_loader.data); 
          dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }
  }
}
```

Now FlexBuilder/FlashBuilder should "autocomplete" the events for that class.
The downside is that you can't use "constants" with the "Event" metadata tag so this :

```
[Event(name=Event.COMPLETE, type="flash.events.Event")]
```

wouldn't work.

You can read more about event/event dispatching [here](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=76FDB).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes this definitely helps.  Thanks very much.